# How to load properties from git under specific branch in Ansible?

Tags: git, ansible

```
- name: load properties
  include_vars:
    dir: "./properties"
    files_matching: "properties.yaml"
```

So this is my current task to load properties, it align with master branch where the main source of my playbook at.

Now, I want the properties but from the other branch, 'test' branch.

How do I do that?
I need to load it from test branch because I need to push additional data to test branch properties file and need the updated properties file of test branch for the next running job.

Comment: Checkout the test branch and run your playbook against it.